# navigation property issue for odata

Tags: c#, linq

I have a view model named ProjectViewModel and normal model named Project.. so I am populating ProjectViewModel through linq query.

But returning below error

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8'.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException","stacktrace":"","internalexception":{
>           "message":"No NavigationLink factory was found for the navigation property 'Subscription' from entity type 'SSAStatusService.Domain.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel' on entity set 'Project'. Try calling HasNavigationPropertyLink on the EntitySetConfiguration.\r\nParameter name: navigationProperty

Below are my classes

```
 public class ProjectViewModel
{
   public String ProjectId { get; set; }

   public String Name { get; set; }

   public List<Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }

}

public class Subscriptions
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}

var query=from p in DataContext.Project 
      join c in DataContext.Subscriptions on p.ProjectId equals c.ProjectId into subs
      select new ProjectViewModel { 
                                    ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                                    Name = p.Name,
                                    Subscriptions=subs.ToList()
                                  };
```

Comment: Looks like the naming convention is confused by the plural name class `Subscriptions`, try to rename the class to `Subscription`.

Comment: That i had tried with that and no luck.. what i understand is that it has something to do with ODataConventionModelBuilder.. but how to solve i dont know